# Dailymotion javascript SDK error with IE

Tags: javascript, sdk, dailymotion-api

I'm using https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-sdk-js for my app and i have an error when i test with IE, in my console i can see an error in the script `all.js` from the SDK :

```
Fichier : all.js, ligne : 1, colonne : 13748
```

This line is :

```
if(DM._session&&"expires" in DM._session&&new Date().getTime()>DM._session.expires*1000
```

What can i do ?

Comment: a fix regarding this issue is incoming, the js SDK is being modified

Answer (score 0):

there was an issue in the SDK, it has now been fixed.